# Feature request: Profanity validation

Tags: feature-request

I have **JUST** come across a question that had an answer containing profanity (flagged and commented for author to change) and I wanted to ask:

- Can we have a feature that scans the questions entirety for **any** profanity and stops the user posting it if there is or changes it to a starred version of said word?

Comment: fkcu you! (just to show how EASY it would be to circumvent these things, this is NOT an insult :P). Dev time can be spent on things that will provide a better value for the site

Comment: It's just really got me worried that places we think should be safe for kids (who do use these sites), can contain such vulgarity. Now I'm no saint, but I keep it away from places where it can be viewed by *a person of a younger age*

Comment: kids should not be using this site. 14 (13?) is the minimum to be on here, and I believe at that point, seeing one or two vulgar words won't destroy you.

Comment: But still, there are a lot of kids learning to program nowadays, who's to say there aren't people of age 13 below on here that can easily view it? I for one wouldn't let my kids on a site where profanity has no form of validation, that's me personal opinion though :)

Comment: And what about questions _specifically_ about validating/filtering profanity? Sure there are ways to ask that without actually using profanity, but if it's an actual part of the question, there's technically nothing wrong being done. Or what about the programming language that is literally named with a profane term? What about that one? Would you completely block questions about that programming language?

Comment: If the language has a profane term, I think that's an oversight on the creators part (IMO), and there are ways to protect people from this, as I say, replace with stars

Comment: Well if the kid comes here breaking the rules, then all goes. It's like saying "we shouldn't serve beer in bars because even though they are to be accessed only by people old enough to drink, people slip in anyway". To me, if the site is supposed to be >13, and you're 10 and here, it's YOUR problem what you see on here, no one else's

Comment: Anyone who really wants to swear will eventually figure out that empty tags will allow you to circumvent it.  Besides, how many 6-year-olds do you expect to be asking for Regex?

Comment: Also [blacklists don't work](https://blog.codinghorror.com/blacklists-dont-work/)

Comment: But won't that be extremely complicated? "Did he mean Brain**** or the actual language? Is there a NEW language that looks like Brain**** that I don't know and that uses stars in its name?"

Comment: Sure, you could replace it with stars. Though that will make the language name harder to search on. (I actually don't work with the language, but the naming is probably some sort of joke on the creators part, actually, and I highly doubt having the f-bomb in a language name is an oversight of any kind.) Making a language hard to search for is going to end up with either 1) _way more_ duplicate questions or 2) a feeling that questions about that language aren't allowed here. (Also, don't think `*` works in tag names, since it's the wildcard for tag searches, so what would you do there?)

Comment: Would a review process work then? When something such as `Brain****` is found, it goes to review to see if it indeed language or someone using it for the sake of it?

Comment: ANOTHER REVIEW QUEUE?! please no... please please please please no. Especially for something like this. If it's vulgar, edit/flag. What's the issue there?

Comment: keep kids safe from... what? words? cmon now... Are you going to pull them out of school too? there's certainly vulgar language used there too, and they're might be disciplined there just like they might be here, if reported.

Comment: The issue to me is a matter of manners and thoughtfulness, the community on SE in general has **always** been amazing and a varied group, to allow profanity is (IMO) to lower the town of the whole SE community, as I said, I am no angel by any stretch, I don't hold back a swear, but there is a place and time for it IMO

Comment: But we don't allow profanity. FLAG IT, you'll see it's not allowed

Comment: And (as stated in my question) I flagged it and here is the result: `offensive – Sam Swift 23 mins ago   declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention`. **DECLINED?!**

Comment: @SamSwift so you used a CUSTOM flag? not a simple "this is rude/offensive?" Then yeah it had reason to be declined. Mods don't accept custom flags that can be taken care of by the community.

Comment: Example? maybe it's something we can help with, given that message.

Comment: Yeah. Because - **other users can edit**. Moderators do not need to be involved.

Comment: I can link the exact post if it helps? The profanity got changed on my comment on it and I used the rude/offensive flag

Comment: Sure you can, but if it's been edited out... the system works? We won't be able to create a parser to catch EVERY instance of profanity... I can easily switch to another language and not get caught, espece de sal...... (I won't swear in French, but you get the intent). How would that parser works? Why not instead make sure our system is quick enough to have these removed, NO MATTER the parser?

Comment: [The post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33760221/revisions), the raw version is what I flagged

Comment: But the profanity **still exists** in the revision history

Comment: You should have just clicked the "edit" button and fixed it. The user wasn't being rude or offensive in this case, it's just a code sample with profanities, which we (you, i, the community) can fix.

Comment: Oh wait... so his code NEEDS rudeness to work, as he's filtering out swears? Then you removing the word for the starred version brings a very interesting question : Should his code work for the starred versions TOO? Because that's what it looks like... looks like he wants "f***" to be seen as profane and bleep it.

Comment: Hell, the question is asking about a profanity filter script!

Comment: But the issue falls in the fact, that although relevant to the question, the user still used it hen there was just as much cause to use f*** this s*** as the edit went to

Comment: Most people don't look at the revision history, so it's not high priority unless the offensive text is _really_ bad. (i.e. hate speech.)

Comment: What I am saying, is not that it should work for `f***` too, but that the language that is there should not have been there in the first instance, the OP will KNOW that it has been changed for a reason and in test scripts change it to the profanity

Comment: so if your FR goes through, OP sends his question likes that, and gets an answer that works for * because whoever answers is not aware of the auto-filter.... we end up with something completely broken...

Comment: Currently it's a case of *my message hasn't been made very clearly*, I will add an edit to my question to try and make the point better

Comment: It doesn't change anything. You BROKE the question by adding this. Someone without context or who doesn't check the revision history has NO WAY to know that the code should work for the unstarred version

Comment: Thena comment on the end saying something like `//Changed to starred for STACK OVERFLOW RULES`

Comment: No, Sam, we get your message. We _disagree completely_ with your message, _especially_ in a case where the _entire point of a post_ is code to handle profanity.

Comment: That comment would mean your starring idea doesn't break posts. It doesn't make it a GOOD idea though.

Comment: May I point all to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/298089)

Comment: Sam, NO ONE SAYS THEY ARE OKAY TO BE USED. We just tell you that there is no reason to have an auto-filter for them, especially with the edge cases out there. You take a simple "the system works and removes these quickly" and turn it into "you guys don't care if it's there"

Comment: But you have just said it is basically as: *Oh wait... so his code NEEDS rudeness to work, as he's filtering out swears? Then you removing the word for the starred version brings a very interesting question : Should his code work for the starred versions TOO? Because that's what it looks like... looks like he wants "f***" to be seen as profane and bleep it. – Patrice 8 mins ago*

Comment: no no, what I said is that the starring of his words is confusing. I didn't say he needs to have the word in his question. He could've used a variable called "fbomb" and say in his post "I am using the fbomb variable as a string that contains an fbomb". No need for star, but no need for the word either

Comment: And that's what I am getting at, ideas for some way to either flag or send to review questions that contain profanity, either as a peer review system or something automatic. As you said: *No need for star, but no need for the word either*. Just some way to keep SE clean

Comment: BUT WHY?! a peer review queue would be slower than you simply editing it... your ideas to make this simpler will just lead to it being viewed by MORE people and taken care of SLOWER...

Comment: But a PRQ system would stop it hitting the public domain before it is reviewed surely? Meaning that if it deemed *required and necessary*, it goes out, else it is held in suspense until it is edited without losing the original context

Comment: I don't want to see questions go unanswered or downvoted because they contain expletives, I want to see the question get answered, someone get a result, and for it to help others. But there are (as you said), ways to do it without the need for either starring or the profanity itself

Comment: I don't believe it's a good idea to hold a post hostage while a review happens on it. Editing IS and REMAINS the quick, easy, and efficient solution here. I'm with you swearing has no place here, but there's no need to throw up such a system for a couple of profane words here and there.

Comment: 1. Ironically, the post you flagged is about implementing a feature to block curse words. 2. How are we going to compile a list of all the words that should be blocked?

Comment: You object to the edit history still containing the word behind a link? The question itself contains a link to a text file with an entire _list_ of curse words. Plus, as Patrice already said, the code in the answer is now broken. This is utter nonsense. A word in itself, like a knife, is not offensive: it must be _used_ in an offensive manner.

Answer (score 11):

By and large, the site has been clean of profanity or anything that professionals in their normal discourse would find offensive.

If you encounter abrasive or truly offensive content in a question or answer, feel encouraged to edit it out as a suggested edit.  If the edit makes its way back into the question, suggest the edit again and flag it for moderator attention.

Creating a feature to do this is not going to be helpful, considering how trivial it is to enter in е and make it look just like a normal, Latin "e" to circumvent filters.